# jquery delay effect

Tags: jquery, delay, timedelay

I am developing a mega menu for an ecommerce site. I have uploaded the current version here: http://www.nicklansdell.com/menu/. The menu works great with or without javascript at the moment. What I would really like is to improve the usability when the user have javascript enable by creating a short delay before the menu animates out. My jquery code so far is:

```
$(function() {
// If no JS CSS menu will still work
$("#menu").removeClass("cssonly");

// Find subnav menus and slide them down
$("#menu li a").hover(function(){ 
    $(this).parent().find("div.subnav").fadeIn(200);
    $(this).parent().hover(function() {
    }, function() {
        // On hovering out slide subnav menus back up
        $(this).parent().find("div.subnav").fadeOut(200);
    })
});
```

});

Can anyone please help me achieve the delay effect? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean that they need to hover over the item for some time before the menu animates.  Use the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin for this instead of hover -- does exactly what I've described.

Comment: @tvanfosson - thats exactly what I want to do. I have had a go at using the hoverIntent plugin as you suggested but it has not worked I have up dated my code above, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mtwallet -- can you define "not work" a little more precisely? Are you getting a javascript error? Does it simply not fire as expected? Did you try removing the "hover" code from the `animateIn` function (can't tell if it's just your post or the actual code that's wrong)?

Comment: I got it working in the end many thanks for your help I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Delay the hover with setTimeout(), 2nd argument being delay in milliseconds

Comment: @ChrisTek How would I do that?

Comment: @mtwallet -- do you just want it to delay the animation or delay before firing the animation so that it doesn't trigger unless you actually stay over the trigger element for a bit.  Using a simple setTimeout() will not do the latter, you'd need to check if the mouse is still over the trigger element after the timeout expires -- this is essentially what the hoverIntent plugin does.

Comment: @tvanfosson - thats exactly what I want to do. I have had a go at using the hoverIntent plugin as you suggested but it has not worked I have up dated my code above, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by tvanfosson:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu li a.link").hoverIntent({
            sensitivity: 3, 
            interval: 200, 
            over: animateOut, 
            timeout: 500, 
            out: animateIn
        });
    }); // close document.ready

    function animateOut(){  
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().find("div.subnav").fadeIn(200);
    }

    function animateIn(){
        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function() {
        // On hovering out fade subnav menus back in
        $(this).parent().find("div.subnav").fadeOut(200);
        $("#menu li a.link").removeClass("current");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this script for a similar function.

`var menu = {};
menu.laatstGeopend = null;
menu.timeoutTime = 1000;
menu.timeout = null;
menu.init = function()
{`

$("#menu>li").hover(
  function() 
  {
   // als laatstegeopend dezelfde is als de huidige, dan de timeout verwijderen
   if($(this).hasClass("hover"))
   {
    clearTimeout(menu.timeout);
   }
   // nieuwe uitschuiven
   else
   {
    $("#menu>li>ul").hide();
    $("#menu>li").not(this).removeClass("hover").removeClass("uitklappen_hover");

```
$(this).addClass("hover"); 
if($(this).hasClass("uitklappen"))
{
 $(this).addClass("uitklappen_hover"); 
}

$(">ul", this).hide().slideDown(300);
```

}

// selectbox in

clearTimeout(menu.timeout);
   menu.timeout = setTimeout(function()
   {
    $(menu.laatstGeopend).removeClass("hover uitklappen_hover");

```
// selectbox in <ie7 tonen
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
 $("select").css({ visibility: 'visible' }); 
}
```

}, menu.timeoutTime);
  }
 );
}